# Regulating voltage to compensate for random motor load

Tags: voltage-regulator, brushless-dc-motor

[image]

I'm currently using an L298N with PWM to control the speed of 2 scalextric cars. I need the cars to move round at a consistent speed, while I understand no 2 motors are the same and simply providing the same voltage won't guarantee that, and as such I have slight variations in the PWM values for each lane depending on the car and my own "by eye" calibration.

However some days one of the cars will have a high amount of internal resistance in that it crawls along while being provided with the same voltage as the other car.

Here is a video demonstrating this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WpusScFLhj4

As you can see about 6V is going through both lanes.

Could I add a linear voltage regulator between the L298N and the lane to make sure it maintains the desired voltage no matter the random load the car's motor seem to be under at that point in time?

Comment: But you said it yourself that providing the same voltage doesn't guarantee the same speed, so what makes you think you need a voltage regulator? I'd say you need to look into control theory, PID regulators and such.

Comment: Also, what purpose does the photo serve? It adds zero information to your question IMO.

Comment: because if  I increase the PWM signal on the car going randomly too slow to compensate for the higher resistance at that moment, the increased source voltage brings the final voltage to match the other car's final voltage (once the resistance of both cars has been taken into effect). So by regulating the voltage to be consistent no matter the load it's automatically doing the calibration?

Comment: Sorry, I simply don't understand what you're saying. I'll stay out of this one and let others answer.

Comment: well my knowledge of electronics is very basic so there's a good chance I don't understand what I'm saying :D

Comment: Given that motors don't manifest a 'random slow down' then the problem is probably due to the power pick up system - either the track needs cleaned or the brushes need replaced/repositioned. Much easier (and cheaper) than trying to devise some sort of interactive control sytem for a 'random' event.

Comment: You could probably mostly overcome your varying contact resistance issues by controlling the *current* delivered to each track rather than the voltage. This is a bit more tricky though since you'll have to measure the current and then adjust your PWM accordingly.

Comment: Your "slow" car seems to load its PWM more heavily than your "fast" car. That would indicate that slow car draws more current. Am guessing a motor/drivetrain problem on the slow car. A track/brush contact problem would be indicated by the "slow" car drawing **less** current than the fast car.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brushed permanent-magnet motor speed can be kept fairly constant by driving it with negative resistance equal to resistance of its armature winding. This assumes that internal motor brush resistance is negligible. In your case, the track/brush contact resistance is **not** negligible, which means that remotely sensing track current can't be done - you'd have to monitor motor current **right at the motor of each car**.
 *Negative resistance drive* requires motor current to be sampled, and used to adjust drive voltage. When your motor draws more current, voltage going in is increased (this is equivalent to negative resistance). So you need extra voltage available.

For example, a motor may have resistance of 10 ohms. With 6v applied, and with no mechanical load, its current is near zero. This suggests that a stalled motor would pull 0.6 A from the 6v supply.
With negative resistance drive, it becomes much harder to stall the motor. A -10 ohm driver would apply 12v to a motor drawing 0.6 A.
This method of speed control is called *feedforward control*. To the extent that the motor's internal resistance is matched by the controller's negative resistance, motor shaft speed remains constant. In practice, the controller has limits to how much voltage it can apply, so its negative resistance fails under extreme load. I've burned my fingers trying to stall a toy motor shaft like yours when driven this way.
In your case, the car's pick-up brushes that contact the track have significant variable resistance that makes remote sensing a difficult problem. If this variable resistance can be made much smaller than motor resistance, then feedforward control of track voltage is a possible solution.

Answer (score 2):

The problem of variable contact resistance in the pick-up system is one important point that was mentioned in a moment by @Jim Dearden. There also could be variations in the axle friction and variations in the motor resistance due to temperature. If the motor temperature varies a lot, that would be caused by the motor overloading due to excess friction or something like that.

You could try using current regulation rather than voltage regulation. That would help with the contact resistance of the pick-up system, but it wouldn't help with the other factors.

The best way to deal with the problem would be to used a closed-loop speed control. For that, you would need a speed sensor and a means of getting the speed signal to the controller. With such small scale cars and an off-board control system, that is probably not practicable.

Cleaning and otherwise servicing the pick-up system may solve a lot of the problem, but that is something that probably needs to be done very-frequetly, essentially constantly.